# Размещение виджета ниже ListView

Tags: java, android, android-xml

Как разместить `TextView` ниже `ListView`?

Я когда в Android Studio смотрю на дизайн приложения, `listView` занимает всё место, и я не могу поставить свой `textView` ниже него.

Comment: уточните, не понятно в чем трудность.

Comment: наверное вы имеете в виду footer http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/114-urok-55-header-i-footer-v-spiskah-headerviewlistadapter.html

Comment: @Likhanov Я когда в android studio смотрю на дизайн приложения -
 listView занимает всё место , и я не могу поставить свой textView ниже него .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разметка для `ListView` на весь экран и под ним `TextView` на стандартную высоту *wrap_content*.

С помощью `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="some text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

С помощью `ConstraintLayout`:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="some text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

В результате в обоих случаях получится примерно следующее:

[image: scrn]

Answer (score 1):

Как один из вариантов:

```
Корневой LinearLayout(vertival) и в нем:
  -ListView
  -TextView
```

Answer (score 1):

Как один из вариантов сделать LinearLayout и распределить в нём вес каждого компонента. Распределение пространства рассчитывается как вес текущего компонента, делённый на общий вес всех компонентов умноженный на размер родительского layout.

В примере ниже 1/2 * size

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
```