# Разметка: разместить Spinner под WebView

Tags: android, разметка

Подскажите, как мне упаковать лайаот, чтобы `WebView` не закрывал собой `Spinner`?
Если упаковываю в `RelativeLayout` даже с атрибутом `android:layout_below="@+id/webView"` у `Spinner`, то `Spinner` накладывается на `WebView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/769246/177345 - по сути та же задача (один view на весь экран, второй под ним)

Answer (score 1):

Так должно получиться:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```